# Display image with QImage and QRect

Tags: c++, image, qt

I'm trying to make a game with Qt, but i can't load an image.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
image.load("F:/My Workspace/sprite.png");
rect = image.rect();
rect.moveTo(5,5);
}
```

This is the constructor of the window. The image doesn't show up. I know how to display image using QLabel, but i want to use QRect features so i can move the image.

Comment: You can't. Your rect is just... a rectangle! It cannot show images.

Comment: Then how did they used the rectangle at the paddle?      http://zetcode.com/tutorials/qt4tutorial/breakoutgame/

Comment: they used `rect` later as a hint to draw image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not how things work. The image isn't displayed because you're not doing anything that would display it. And the `rect` you get from `image.rect()` is just a set of numbers. It is not connected to the image in any way, so changing it won't alter the image whether it is displayed or not.

Here are four ways to do what you want:

1. Override `paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)`, and draw the image where you want using one of `QPainter`'s [`drawImage`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#drawImage-8) routines.
2. Use a `QLabel`, set its icon, and use layouts to place it where you want.
3. Use any type of `QWidget`, and set a [style sheet](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet.html) with a background image. Again, use layouts (or absolute positioning) to get it where you want.
4. Use the [Graphics View](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/graphicsview.html) framework if you need a lot of such elements.

There are a few other variations on those, depending on your exact requirements. Check out the [painting examples](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/examples-painting.html), and the [`QPainter`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html) docs.